# Tailwindcss not taking effect when i use it in html file

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have installed tailwindcss using PostCSS. However it's not taking effect when i try to use it to style my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/output.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
```

Here is the output in tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i changed the path to  ../dist/output.css

```html
<link href="../dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it is not properly pointing to the right output.css file location

Comment: Did you manage to solve your own issue?  If yes, then please give the "tick" to accept your own answer.

Comment: i dont have rights to tick the answer as accept.